# Why isn't my border/boundary not working for my turtle object?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm making the snake game through python turtle but for some reason my border collision code isnt working. It worked for a similarly designed pong game but when the snake head moves out of the window screen it doesnt follow the return goto(0,0) function I set for it. Any ideas where the mistake might be? below is a summary of the total script.

```
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(1)
head.shape('square')
head.color('black')
head.penup()
head.goto(0, -100)

wn.setup(width = 500, height = 500)

def snake_up(): #this is the same function used for the downward while left and right function uses head.forward(8)
    y = head.ycor()
    y += 20
    head.sety(y)
    while snake_up():
    head.dy = 8

#keyboard binding uses wn.onkeypress(snake_up, 'i') format

while True:
    wn.update()

    if head.ycor() > 240:
        head.goto(0,0)
    #above is same for all other borders
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is suspicious:

```
def snake_up():
    y = head.ycor()
    y += 20
    head.sety(y)
    while snake_up():
    head.dy = 8
```

Specifically the line `while snake_up():` which makes no sense as `snake_up()` doesn't explicitly return a value so it always returns `None` to the `while` test.  Superficially, that makes this line appear to be a no-op but the reality is it's an infinite recursion as it always calls itself unconditionally before it ever gets a chance to return `None`.

**Update**: I would have written your code example more like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def snake_up():
    y = head.ycor() + 20

    if y > 240:
        head.goto(0, 0)
    else:
        head.sety(y)

def snake_right():
    x = head.xcor() + 20

    if x > 240:
        head.goto(0, 0)
    else:
        head.setx(x)

def move():
    if direction:
        direction()

    screen.ontimer(move, 100)

def set_direction(method):
    global direction

    direction = method

screen = Screen()

head = Turtle()
head.shape('square')
head.speed('fastest')
head.penup()
head.sety(-100)

screen.setup(width=500, height=500)

screen.onkeypress(lambda: set_direction(snake_right), 'k')
screen.onkeypress(lambda: set_direction(snake_up), 'i')
screen.listen()

direction = None

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: By following the code for the snake_up() function suggested by cdlane, the snake head doesn't continuously move forward. Thus, even though the while snake_up() is a bit weird, without it, my snake doesnt move forward unless i press the key everytime

Comment: @kimiitup, I've modified the code to keep the snake moving once the key is pressed and added a second direction to verify things are working.